# Disable Windows machine visibility in network

Tags: windows-8.1, network-shares, shared-folders, homegroup

How can I disable visibility of Windows machine in network without disabling network share discovery? I mean that my PC is visible by other PCs in the network. I'd like to only see other machines but not expose my machine (especially I don't even share anything). It's visible as Computer and as Media Device

Comment: You can't, in order to see other machines, you have to announce yourself

Comment: @Ramhound while that makes sense. If you access smb from a Linux machine, that machine won't be visible to network. Maybe he can use a 3rd party software, don't know

Comment: I assume we're talking only about Windows 8.1 machines

Comment: Yeah i got your point, he can maybe use a 3rd party software to access smb and disable discovery on his windows

Comment: But I never had such issue before on other machines. I mean when I click Network I can see my own machine listed. As in: C:/Users/lapsio is the same as //SWEG-MACHINE/lapsio. Before I never saw the same machine listed in Network shares. Even after disabling Users directory share it's still visible, just no shares available.

Comment: The thing is network is **not** trusted. In fact I can't think of any less trusted network ever because it's virtualized lab network running on Linux host for malware testing, yet I have to turn on network shares in order to get VirtualBox shared folder appear. So it doesn't make sense lol. I feel a bit insecure when this machine is highly visible in network with other compromised virtual machines bridged.